# NESTED IF AND formula problems

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I need a formula that can that tests multiple logical conditions and give answers based on the criteria.

for example if E12=FIRST AND G=12= ABOVE 40 the result should be K8

so i used the this formula `IF(AND(E2= FIRST ,G2= ABOVE 40 ),K8)`

and it works but the FIRST and ABOVE 40 cells are changeable to

```
A.FIRST-ABOVE 40 =K8
B.FIRST-BELOW 40 =K9
C.SECOND-ABOVE 40 =K10
D.SECOND-BELOW 40 =K11
E.THIRD-ABOVE 40 =K12
F.THIRD-BELOW 40 =K13
```

I think i need a nested IF AND formula but i cant quite figure it out.

[[image: Picture of sample data]]

Comment: =IF(E2="FISRT",IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K8,IF(E2="FIRST",IF(G2="BELOW 40",K9))),IF(AND(E2="SECOND",G12="ABOVE 40"),K10,IF(AND(E2="SECOND",G2="BELOW 40"),K11,IF(AND(E2="THIRD",F2="ABOVE 40"),K12)))) if you have an article on the subject im willing to read because combining formulas always gives me problems

Comment: one thing I do when combine formulas is to put each part into a separate cell.  usually in the same row or column depending on how I am thinking at the time.  Above or to the left I will usually write out the logic portion with the IFs, AND, and OR statements which reference the different cells in the column/row.  When everything is working as intended, I go into each cell highlight the formula and copy it.  I then go to the previous cell where it was being referenced and pasted into the spot where the cell reference letters are.  Its a good way to keep things readable and check for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(E2="FIRST",IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K8,K9),IF(E2="SECOND",IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K10,K11),IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K12,K13)))
```

Now that will do what you described above (or at least should).  So while I was entering I made a couple of important assumptions.  E2 will only ever have FIRST, SECOND or THIRD in it.  The if statement above checks for FIRST or SECOND and any entry that is not those two is assumed to be THIRD.  Next is G2 will always either be ABOVE 40 or BELOW 40.  It can never be equal to 40.  Any value that is not ABOVE 40 will return the value for BELOW 40.

There are ways to fix some of those potential pitfalls but I did not want to spoon feed you everything.

you may want to look at adding an if statement in front of all that to make the displayed results equal to nothing if there is no entry in E2 or G2.

## EDIT

Description of what is happening with the IF statement.  Think of the If statement as follows:

```
IF(some sort of true false check,  True action, False action)
```

So in your case the true false check is what is happening with Cell E2.  Does cell E2 equal the word FIRST (also referred to as a string).  So the formula now looks like

```
IF (E2="FIRST", FIRST'S TRUE ACTION, FIRST'S FALSE ACTION)
```

You got that part on your own.  So now we figure out what are we going to do if its true.  So in your Case you want to check G2 and see if its equal to the string ABOVE 40.  So now we have our first nested if.

```
IF (E2="FIRST", IF(G2="ABOVE 40", First's Above True action, first's above False action), First's False Action)
```

So using some of the assumptions I made based on your description, the only option for G2 if it is not ABOVE 40 is for it to be BELOW 40.  As such I do not need to make another check with an if statement as to what G2 might be.  I can just say that if its not ABOVE 40 then my check is FALSE meaning its below 40 and I can just return the false results.  So in your case this would boild down to the following for the first nest:

```
IF (E2="FIRST", IF(G2="ABOVE 40", K8, K9), First's False Action)
```

So now we know what happens as long as E2 is equal to "First".  Now you need to figure out what happens to E2 when its equal to something else.  So we wind up with the next iteration.

```
IF (E2="FIRST", IF(G2="ABOVE 40", K8, K9), IF (E2="SECOND", Second's True Action, Second's False Action))
```

And then we need to check second for ABOVE/BELOW like we did previously and we wind up with:

```
IF (E2="FIRST", IF(G2="ABOVE 40", K8, K9), IF (E2="SECOND", IF(G2="ABOVE 40", K10, K11), Second's False Action))
```

We could keep building checks in for what E2 is by dropping the check into the false action section.  However in your case we know there are only three possible values.  So if E2 is not equal to FIRST, and when we check and find that its not equal to SECOND, then by your definition of the problem it has to euql to 3rd and we do not bother checking this.  We just need to check if it is above or below 40 so we wind up with the formula at the top.

Comment: =IF(E2="FIRST",IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K8,K9) this part i understand but IF(E2="SECOND",IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K10,K11),IF(G2="ABOVE 40",K12,K13))) if im reading it correctly its an IF in side an IF function?

Comment: correct that it is an IF statement inside an IF statement.  That is my understanding of what nested IF statements are.  There is a limit supposedly to how many levels or embedded if statements you can have.  I have not run into this issue myself, but I have run into the issue of maximum number of characters in a formula.  unfortunately I do not know what either of those limits are off the top of my head.